# Angular - Excluir URL o un directiorio de la aplicación

Tags: angular, cors, angular-router

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en **Angular** y me gustaría saber si puedo **excluir una URL o un directorio** del la "aplicación" de modo que si entro por ejemplo a `www.dominio.com/api/` me cargue el contenido del directorio `/public_html/api/` y si no, que siga las instrucciones del controlador de rutas como de costumbre.

El motivo de esto es porque quiero tener la API en el mismo dominio para evitar problemas la [política del CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (no soy muy experto en esos temas y tengo miedo a no proteger la api de la forma adecuada, de este modo me evito algunos problemas).

Answer (score 0):

Pues claro que si amigo, no conozco la estrutura de tu proyecto pero facilmente puedes puedes hacer un redirect si por alguna motivo la api no se carga y rediridir hacia una vista.

Te dejo el ejemplo de un login pero puedes aplicar el mismo principio

```
this.auth.logIn(this.usuario)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        console.log('user is logged');
        Swal.close();
        // si esta el check activo almacena el email en el local storage
        if (this.recordar) {
          localStorage.setItem('email', this.usuario.email);
        }
        // limpiando error de local storage y navegando al home
        localStorage.removeItem('error');
        this.route.navigateByUrl('/dashboar/grafics');
      }, (err) => {
        // manejando el error
        this.errores = this.errores + 1;
        // verificacion para recatcha
        if (this.errores > 1) {
          localStorage.setItem('error', '2');
          this.recpcha = true;
          this.clear = false;
          location.reload();
        }
        console.log(err.error.error.message);
        // modal de error
        Swal.fire({
          text: err.error.error.message,
          icon: 'error',
        });
      });
  }
```